# tablet as a keyboard (bluetooth / USB)

Tags: communication

what would it take to get a tablet to communicate with a desktop via bluetooth (or USB)? There are some programs such as remotemouse which do this through WLAN.

Comment: I'm an absolute noob, so I have no idea how this would work. Just would like to know how hard it would be (costs/effort). So there is a standard USB to bluetooth adapter I suppose, and I would have to write my own driver? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get an android tablet, root it, and run [blueputdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=berserker.android.apps.blueputdroid).  This is not related to electrical engineering.